# Retrieving data from database includes some characters if the data has some special symbol in it

Tags: java, spring

The database contains `LasAmêricas` I am getting the value as `Las Am├⌐ricas`
also if `20.7.2017` it is getting as `20.7.2017.@pafg` .I am retrieving data in records object format which is a list.Please let me know how I can get the actual database value when retrieved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is your application a web-application ? If yes, then which application server are you using ? It looks like encoding format _UTF-8_  is not set.

Comment: This issue is due to charset/codepage. Please try "UTF-8". This should be set where you establish connection to database.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value in string format and then adding it to a list